# CloudFlare & Dynamic Origin IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, cloudflare

How can I specify a dynamic IP address for the origin server when configuring Cloudflare?

For instance, when using EC2, the IP address may change whenever the instance is restarted?

How do you update CloudFlare to automatically forward traffic to the new IP address when the origin server IP address has changed?

Comment: Use a Load Balancer with a static IP.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

1. Assign an Elastic IP to the EC2 instance so that the IP address will never change.
2. Place an Elastic Load Balancer in front of the instance and create a CNAME record in CloudFlare that points to the ELB's dns name.
3. Add a script to your EC2 instance that runs on bootup, that makes a call to the CloudFlare API to update the DNS entry with its new IP address.